# What does ReactClass<*> mean?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm seeing `ReactClass<*>` in [code for React-Navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/b759d3136e4c3d69fb72816819c66f50ecebf8d1/src/views/TabView/TabView.js#L19). I have two questions:

- Why does `ReactClass` not need importing at the top of the file? Is it some kind of global constant in React Native?
- What is the meaning of `ReactClass<*>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an *existential type* [in Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/classes/) of a React Component.

In short, they're saying expect that `tabBarComponent` may or may not be there (note the question mark at the end of `tabBarComponent?`, and that it will be a React component class, with arguments of a type that *flow will infer*.

Flow is a tool for making JavaScript [strongly typed](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/strongly-typed).